# How to update remote server application from local server application

Tags: php, mysql, unix, wamp, lamp

I have a PHP/MySQL application running with WAMP on a local server. This application contains sensitive and confidential data that can only be accessed from devices on the network in the office.

However, this application generates reports that clients should be able to access from the web from an entirely separate application running on a LAMP stack.

Currently, I have the reports transferring via SFTP from the local server to the web based server.

My question is, how can I update the remote database from the local application securely, and so that the MySQL db can only be modified by the localhost of the remote application and the server running the local application?

I'm thinking about creating some kind of API that only accepts data from the IP of the local app, but I do not know the best practices for this, nor do I know how to start going about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL provides a USER > **FROM HOST** > PER DATABASE > PER TABLE > PER COLUMN grant system.

Meaning that you can specify which user can connect from **which host** to which database,... Make usage of the FROM HOST feature.